# error: no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::istream

Tags: c++, c++11

I am reading the c++ primer 5th edition.I have a bare bones Sales_item class. This is main.cpp file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Sales_item.h"

int main() {
Sales_item book;
std::cin >> book ;
}
```

Sales_item.h

```
#ifndef BOOKSTORE_SALES_ITEM_H
#define BOOKSTORE_SALES_ITEM_H
#include <iostream>

class Sales_item {

};


#endif //BOOKSTORE_SALES_ITEM_H
```

Sales_item.cpp is empty. I am following the c++ primer book. So I am assuming it is to be left empty at this point.

I get this error and build fails.

`error: no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::istream {aka std::basic_istream<char>}' and 'Sales_item')`

Comment: I'm going to guess you have not implemented the operator in your class. The reason I have to guess is you haven't shown your class.

Comment: You will have to overload `>>` for `Sales_item`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Show us the definition of Sales_item class ? Post the relevant code in your question

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: first, why do you want to do a `cin` for an empty class when it doesn't have any variables. second, if you add some class memebers, you should tell the compiler that when you do a `cin`, to what member it should add the accepted value. For this, you need to overload the  `operator>>`, so when the compiler comes across such operator in conjunction with your class type object, it'll refer to your class member function rather than normal `<<operator` present in `iostream`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make any sense to do a `std::cin` for an empty `class`. Why will you do that if your `class` itself is empty ?

But I think you need to do this

See live demo [here](http://cpp.sh/3noh)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class Sales_item {
    std::string m_item_name;
    int m_itemno;

    public:
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& o,Sales_item& obj) {
        o>>obj.m_item_name>>obj.m_itemno;
        return o;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o,const Sales_item& obj) {
        o<<obj.m_item_name<<' '<<obj.m_itemno;
        return o;
    }

};

int main() {
    Sales_item s;
    std::cin>>s;
    std::cout<<s;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You could, for demonstration purposes, overload `operator<<` instead of `display()`, for symmetry.

Comment: ``std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& o,Sales_item& obj)`` Is this an edit to the istream constructor in this class? I cannot understand it for now. but it can be used nonetheless.